# Map URL with folder on Tomcat

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat, virtualhost, httpd

I have a Java webservice running on Tomcat (`/opt/tomcat8/webapps/mysvr`) that is accessed through url `http://mysvr.example.com`. It works fine with the following configuration on `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysvr.example.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/mysvr/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/mysvr/
</VirtualHost>
```

In addition want to use the URL `http://mysvr.example.com/results/` to map `/var/www/html/mysvr/results`, where I am storing some txt files, so that URL `http://mysvr.example.com/results/1.txt` downloads `/var/www/html/mysvr/results/1.txt`.

My server is AWS EC2 on Red Hat.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Alias /results /var/www/html/mysvr/results
ProxyPass /results !
```

This excludes /results from being passed to tomcat. The first line is optional if the results folder is in the correct place in the document root.
Be sure to include this ProxyPass line before the others to make it work.